# Email to specific shop manager : Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a plugin where a customer(s) is attached to a shop manager. The shop manager can only see orders of customers that are attached to him. The plugin has two parts :

The first one, i already built it, hide all orders that aren't attached to a shop manager. Here's the code in case you want to see how it works :

```
function before_checkout_create_order($order, $data) {

    $store_manager_id = '';

    switch ($order->get_user_id()) {
        case 34:
            $store_manager_id = 18;
            break;

        case 33:
            $store_manager_id = 20;
            break;
    }

    $order->update_meta_data('_store_manager_id', $store_manager_id);
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);

function custom_admin_shop_manager_orders($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;

    $currentUserRoles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if (in_array('shop_manager', $currentUserRoles)) {
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
                isset($qv['post_type']) && $qv['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
            // I use the meta key from step 1 as a second parameter here
            $query->set('meta_key', '_store_manager_id');
            // The value we want to find is the $user_id defined above
            $query->set('meta_value', $user_id);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_admin_shop_manager_orders');

?>
```

**The second part where i need help :** I'm trying to have emails only for the shop manager concerned.

Eg : A customer order some products, the shop manager attached to him receives an email about his order but all others shop managers dont receive anything.

If you have any ideas feel free !

Comment: Send email when customer place an order. You can use woocommerce_thankyou hook which have order ID so easly you can grab your manager email and use wp_mail().

Comment: I have similar project where i use woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order to send new order email to my main emails from woocommerce settings + my vendor i can share the solution with you if you want to use email hooks. I use this  bcs i need for different emails to notify him so its more consistant with my plugin.

Comment: I'm kinda new to the world of Wordpress Hooks so yeah if you have any piece of code that could help me understand how you built it that'll be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following function in your functions.php

Using `woocommerce_thankyou` hook

```
function notify_store_manager($order_get_id) {
    //Get current order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_get_id );
    //Get the manager id for this order
    $manager_id = $order->get_meta('_store_manager_id');
    //Get manager data 
    $manager = get_userdata($manager_id);
    //Get manager email address
    $manager_email = $manager->user_email;

    //Build your email info
    $order_id  = $order->get_id();

    $to = $manager_email;
    $subject = 'You have new order'.$order_id.'';
    $body = 'You have new order with id '.$order_id.'';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'notify_store_manager', 10);
```

Comment: Just to be sure : How does the order get the manager id ?

Comment: In your function before_checkout_create_order u set order meta ?

Comment: I'm dumb... Been a long time since i've worked on the project ^^ Thank you !